# Cannot get data from a db to an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Basically i have an application that gets data from an api (top anime and top manga) until now everything is going good, animes are seen in the activity in a clean way and everything but now i'm blocked in a parte where i have to add the anime clicked (in the recyclerView i added a + botton that when clicked the anime has to be added from the AnimeListActivity to the AnimeFavouriteList) but that doesn't happend..i created the db and it works, when i click it can be seen in the db but not in the right activity what should i do?

I created the daos the roomlocalservice and everything
this is the all the code i have about this part

```
class AnimeListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: AnimeListAdapter
private lateinit var animeListViewModel: AnimeListViewModel
private lateinit var roomFavouriteLocalService: RoomFavouriteLocalService
private lateinit var searchInputLayout: TextInputLayout
private lateinit var searchInputEditText: TextInputEditText
private lateinit var buttonSearch: Button
private lateinit var animeDao: AnimeDao
private lateinit var mangaDao: MangaDao

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime_list)
    
        val animeRepository = AnimeRepository(RemoteApi.animeService)
        val animeDao = FavouriteDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).animeDao()
        val mangaDao = FavouriteDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).mangaDao()
        val localService = RoomFavouriteLocalService(animeDao, mangaDao)
        val viewModelFactory = AnimeListViewModelFactory(animeRepository, localService)
    
        animeListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AnimeListViewModel::class.java)
    
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.animeBottomNavigationView)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        searchInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.anime_searchInputLayout)
        searchInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.anime_searchInputEditText)
        buttonSearch = findViewById(R.id.anime_buttonSearch)
    
        roomFavouriteLocalService = RoomFavouriteLocalService(animeDao, mangaDao)
        adapter = AnimeListAdapter(animeListViewModel.animeList.value ?: emptyList(), roomFavouriteLocalService)
    
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int){
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
    
                val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager
                val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
                val lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                if (totalItemCount <= lastVisibleItem + 2) {
                    animeListViewModel.loadMoreAnime()
                }
            }
        })
    
        animeListViewModel.animeList.observe(this, Observer { anime ->
            adapter.setData(anime)
        })
    
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_animeList -> true
                R.id.menu_animeFavouriteList -> {
                    Intent(this, AnimeFavouriteList::class.java).also {
                        startActivity(it)
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).also {
                        startActivity(it)
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val searchTerm = searchInputEditText.text.toString()
            animeListViewModel.searchAnime(searchTerm)
        }
    
        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.menu_animeList
    }

}

class AnimeFavouriteList : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
private lateinit var favouriteAnimeRecylerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var roomFavouriteLocalService: RoomFavouriteLocalService
private lateinit var adapter: AnimeFavouriteAdapter
private lateinit var animeDao: AnimeDao
private lateinit var mangaDao: MangaDao
private lateinit var viewModel: AnimeListViewModel
private lateinit var animeRepository: AnimeRepository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourite_anime_list)
    
        val favouriteDatabase = FavouriteDatabase.getDatabase(application)
    
        animeDao = favouriteDatabase.animeDao()
        mangaDao = favouriteDatabase.mangaDao()
        animeRepository = AnimeRepository(animeService)
        roomFavouriteLocalService = RoomFavouriteLocalService(animeDao, mangaDao)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, AnimeListViewModelFactory(animeRepository, roomFavouriteLocalService)).get(AnimeListViewModel::class.java)
        adapter = AnimeFavouriteAdapter(emptyList())
    
        Log.d("AnimeFavouriteList", "onCreate() executed")
    
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.animeBottomNavigationView)
        favouriteAnimeRecylerView = findViewById(R.id.animeFavouriteRecyclerView)
        favouriteAnimeRecylerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        favouriteAnimeRecylerView.adapter = adapter
    
        viewModel.getFavouriteAnimeFromLocal().observe(this, Observer {
            anime -> adapter.setData(anime)
        })
    
        favouriteAnimeRecylerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
    
                val layoutManager = favouriteAnimeRecylerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
                val lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    
            }
        })
    
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_animeList -> {
                    Intent(this, AnimeListActivity::class.java).also {
                        startActivity(it)
                    }
                    true
                }
    
                R.id.menu_animeFavouriteList -> {
                    true
                }
    
                else -> {
                    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).also {
                        startActivity(it)
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
        }
        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.menu_animeFavouriteList
    }
}

class AnimeListViewModel(
private val animeRepository: AnimeRepository,
private val localService: FavouriteLocalService
) : ViewModel() {
private var _animeListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<AnimeModel>>()
private var initialPage = 1
private var currentPage = initialPage
private val perPage = 10
private var isLoading = false

    var animeList: LiveData<List<AnimeModel>> = _animeListLiveData
    
    init {
        getTopAnime()
    }
    
    fun getTopAnime(page: Int = 1, perPage: Int = 10) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                if (!isLoading) {
                    isLoading = true
                    val animeList = animeRepository.getTopAnime(page, perPage)
                    val uiAnime = animeList.data.map {
                        AnimeModel(
                            mal_id = it.mal_id,
                            url = it.url,
                            images = it.images.jpg.image_url,
                            trailer = it.trailer,
                            approved = it.approved,
                            titles = it.titles,
                            title = it.title,
                            title_japanese = it.title_japanese,
                            title_synonyms = it.title_synonyms,
                            title_english = it.title_english,
                            type = it.type,
                            source = it.source,
                            episodes = it.episodes,
                            status = it.status,
                            airing = it.airing,
                            aired = it.aired,
                            duration = it.duration,
                            rating = it.rating,
                            score = it.score,
                            scored_by = it.scored_by,
                            rank = it.rank,
                            popularity = it.popularity,
                            members = it.members,
                            favorites = it.favorites,
                            synopsis = it.synopsis,
                            background = it.background,
                            broadcast = it.broadcast,
                            producers = it.producers,
                            licensors = it.licensors,
                            studios = it.studios,
                            genres = it.genres,
                            explicit_genres = it.explicit_genres,
                            themes = it.themes,
                            demographics = it.demographics
                        )
                    }
                    _animeListLiveData.postValue(uiAnime)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun getFavouriteAnimeFromLocal(): LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>> {
        return localService.getFavouriteAnime()
    }
    
    fun loadMoreAnime() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                if (!isLoading) {
                    isLoading = true
                    currentPage++
                    val animeList = animeRepository.getTopAnime(currentPage, perPage)
                    val uiAnime = animeList.data.map {
                        AnimeModel(
                            mal_id = it.mal_id,
                            url = it.url,
                            images = it.images.jpg.image_url,
                            trailer = it.trailer,
                            approved = it.approved,
                            titles = it.titles,
                            title = it.title,
                            title_japanese = it.title_japanese,
                            title_synonyms = it.title_synonyms,
                            title_english = it.title_english,
                            type = it.type,
                            source = it.source,
                            episodes = it.episodes,
                            status = it.status,
                            airing = it.airing,
                            aired = it.aired,
                            duration = it.duration,
                            rating = it.rating,
                            score = it.score,
                            scored_by = it.scored_by,
                            rank = it.rank,
                            popularity = it.popularity,
                            members = it.members,
                            favorites = it.favorites,
                            synopsis = it.synopsis,
                            background = it.background,
                            broadcast = it.broadcast,
                            producers = it.producers,
                            licensors = it.licensors,
                            studios = it.studios,
                            genres = it.genres,
                            explicit_genres = it.explicit_genres,
                            themes = it.themes,
                            demographics = it.demographics
                        )
                    }
                    _animeListLiveData.postValue(_animeListLiveData.value.orEmpty() + uiAnime)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun resetPage() {
        currentPage = initialPage
        animeRepository.resetPage()
        _animeListLiveData.value = emptyList()
        getTopAnime()
    }
    
    fun searchAnime(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val animeList = animeRepository.searchAnime(query)
                val uiAnime = animeList.data.map {
                    AnimeModel(
                        mal_id = it.mal_id,
                        url = it.url,
                        images = it.images.jpg.image_url,
                        trailer = it.trailer,
                        approved = it.approved,
                        titles = it.titles,
                        title = it.title,
                        title_japanese = it.title_japanese,
                        title_synonyms = it.title_synonyms,
                        title_english = it.title_english,
                        type = it.type,
                        source = it.source,
                        episodes = it.episodes,
                        status = it.status,
                        airing = it.airing,
                        aired = it.aired,
                        duration = it.duration,
                        rating = it.rating,
                        score = it.score,
                        scored_by = it.scored_by,
                        rank = it.rank,
                        popularity = it.popularity,
                        members = it.members,
                        favorites = it.favorites,
                        synopsis = it.synopsis,
                        background = it.background,
                        broadcast = it.broadcast,
                        producers = it.producers,
                        licensors = it.licensors,
                        studios = it.studios,
                        genres = it.genres,
                        explicit_genres = it.explicit_genres,
                        themes = it.themes,
                        demographics = it.demographics
                    )
                }
                _animeListLiveData.postValue(uiAnime)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun addToFavourites(anime: AnimeModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val animeEntity = AnimeEntity(anime.mal_id, anime.title, anime.images)
            localService.addAnimeToFavourites(animeEntity)
        }
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "anime_table") 
data class AnimeEntity(     
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)     
@ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int = 0,     
@ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,     
@ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl") val imageUrl: String )

class AnimeFavouriteAdapter(
private var animeList: List<AnimeEntity>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimeFavouriteAdapter.AnimeFavouriteViewHolder>(){

    class AnimeFavouriteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val animeImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAnimeImageView)
        val titleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAnimeTitleTextView)
    }
    
    
    fun setData(newAnimeList: List<AnimeEntity>) {
        animeList = newAnimeList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AnimeFavouriteViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_anime, parent, false)
        return AnimeFavouriteViewHolder(view)
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnimeFavouriteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val anime = animeList[position]
    
        Picasso.get().load(anime.imageUrl).into(holder.animeImage)
    
        val truncatedTitle = if (anime.title.length > 14) {
            anime.title.substring(0, 14) + "..."
        } else {
            anime.title
        }
        holder.titleTextView.text = truncatedTitle
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return animeList.size
    }
}

class RoomFavouriteLocalService(
private val animeDao: AnimeDao,
private val mangaDao: MangaDao
) : FavouriteLocalService {

    private val _favouriteAnime = MutableLiveData<List<AnimeEntity>>()
    private val _favouriteManga = MutableLiveData<List<MangaEntity>>()
    
    override suspend fun addAnimeToFavourites(anime: AnimeEntity) {
        animeDao.insert(anime)
        refreshFavouriteAnime()
    }
    
    override fun getFavouriteAnime(): LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>> {
        return _favouriteAnime
    }
    
    override suspend fun removeAnimeFromFavourites(anime: AnimeEntity) {
        animeDao.delete(anime)
        refreshFavouriteAnime()
    }
    
    // aggiorna il LiveData dopo le operazioni di aggiunta/rimozione
    private fun refreshFavouriteAnime() {
        _favouriteAnime.postValue(animeDao.getAllAnime().value)
    }
    
    override suspend fun addMangaToFavourites(manga: MangaEntity) {
        mangaDao.insert(manga)
        refreshFavouriteManga()
    }
    
    override fun getFavouriteManga(): LiveData<List<MangaEntity>> {
        return _favouriteManga
    }
    
    override suspend fun removeMangaFromFavourites(manga: MangaEntity) {
        mangaDao.delete(manga)
        refreshFavouriteManga()
    }
    
    // aggiorna il LiveData dopo le operazioni di aggiunta/rimozione
    private fun refreshFavouriteManga() {
        _favouriteManga.postValue(mangaDao.getAllManga().value)
    }

}

interface FavouriteLocalService {
suspend fun addAnimeToFavourites(anime: AnimeEntity)
fun getFavouriteAnime(): LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>>
suspend fun removeAnimeFromFavourites(anime: AnimeEntity)

    suspend fun addMangaToFavourites(mangaEntity: MangaEntity)
    fun getFavouriteManga(): LiveData<List<MangaEntity>>
    suspend fun removeMangaFromFavourites(mangaEntity: MangaEntity)

}

@Database(entities = [AnimeEntity::class, MangaEntity::class], version = 3, exportSchema = false)`
abstract class FavouriteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun animeDao(): AnimeDao
    abstract fun mangaDao(): MangaDao
    
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: FavouriteDatabase? = null
    
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "favourite_database"
    
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): FavouriteDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    FavouriteDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                )
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }

}

@Dao
interface AnimeDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insert(anime: AnimeEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM anime_table")
    fun getAllAnime(): LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>>
    
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(anime: AnimeEntity)

}
```

ps. for the manga part is the same

Comment: When addToFavourites is called, what is in charge of updating the UI (not the DB)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a debugger in

```
private fun refreshFavouriteAnime() {
    _favouriteAnime.postValue(animeDao.getAllAnime().value)
}
```

because i think when you are inserting the anime and then calls the refresh function it maybe does not update the list because the insert is not yet done as we know insert is async so you have to manage that by using await or there is an other solution
instead of doing this

```
override fun getFavouriteAnime(): LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>> {
    return _favouriteAnime
}
```

you can do this

RoomFavouriteLocalService :

```
 val favouriteAnime :LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>>() 
     get() = _favouriteAnime 

 override fun getFavouriteAnime(){
    _favouriteAnime.postValue(animeDao.getAllAnime().value)  
}
```

and in viewmodel you have to do this :

```
val favAnimeList: LiveData<List<AnimeEntity>> 
     get() = localService.favouriteAnime

init {
    getTopAnime()
    localService.getFavouriteAnime()
}
```

and now you have to observe favAnimeList in activity and set the adapter like this :

Activity AnimeFavList :

```
viewModel.favAnimeList.observe(this, Observer {
            anime -> adapter.setData(anime)
        })
```